# Python to construct CASE WHEN update SQL statement

Tags: sql, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bq

I try to update 2K rows in BQ

```
def update_bq_ads_status_failed(self, update_ads):
    affected_rows = 0
    for update_ads_chunk in split(update_ads, _UPDATE_CHUNK_SIZE):
        ad_ids = [item["ad_id"] for item in update_ads_chunk]
        removal_errors = [item["removal_error"] for item in update_ads_chunk]

        update_removal_error = ""
        for ad_id, removal_error in zip(ad_ids, removal_errors):
            update_removal_error = update_removal_error + \
                                   f''' WHEN ad_id = '{ad_id}' Then '{removal_error}' '''
        affected_rows += self.update_bq_ads_status(f"""
                        UPDATE '{table_full_name}' 
                        SET status = 'Failed Removing'  
            SET removal_error = CASE {update_removal_error} END 
            WHERE ad_id IN {str(ad_ids)}
            """)
    return affected_rows
```

I'm getting this error. I know it's too vague and not possible to debug like this.

> timeout=300.0, headers={'X-Server-Timeout': '300.0',
> 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
> 'X-Goog-API-Client': 'gl-python/3.8.10 grpc/1.39.0 gax/2.0.0
> gapic/2.26.0 gccl/2.26.0', 'User-Agent': 'gl-python/3.8.10 grpc/1.39.0
> gax/2.0.0 gapic/2.26.0 gccl/2.26.0'})), last exception: ('Connection
> aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without
> response'))

I'm trying to eliminate errors. Is my BQ update syntactically correct?

What's the BQ update timeout?

Comment: Could it be that as you've defined `$update_removal_error`, it's inclusion in the query becomes `SET removal_error = CASE WHEN ad_id = {ad_id} Then removal_error = {removal_error}`? Notice that for your specified case the clause becomes `removal_error = removal_error = {removal_error}`.

Comment: Thanks both. I have edited my code. I think it looks better now.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error after your code edit? Is this the actual code you are running? It just looks like a standard timeout error - your query is taking too long.  Perhaps you can increase the timeout from 300.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I will try again. I will google how to increase the timeout in BQ and in Google -Ads api.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've tried to increase the G-Ads API timeout, but I see no timeout field in the proto https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/4006aa5cbd12a86550d45fb215511a98a697f48f/google/ads/googleads/v8/services/google_ads_service.proto#L449, despite this php doc: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs/php/timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues with last `UPDATE` statement:

- Avoid quoting identifiers like table names (unless GBQ allows its)
- `SET` should be used once with comma separation for multiple columns
- Square brackets are interpolated in `WHERE` condition which requires parentheses

Consider adjusted code:

```py
update_removal_error = " ".join(
    f"WHEN ad_id = '{ad_id}' THEN '{removal_error}'"
    for ad_id, removal_error in zip(ad_ids, removal_errors)
)

affected_rows += self.update_bq_ads_status(f"""
    UPDATE {table_full_name}
    SET status = 'Failed Removing'  
      , removal_error = CASE {update_removal_error} END 
     WHERE ad_id IN {tuple(ad_ids)}
""")
```